# How to send data to vertex shader with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, vertex

I've got some problem with sending data to my vertex shader :

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 5) in vec3 in_Vertex;
layout (location = 6) in vec3 in_Color;

in int gl_InstanceID;

layout (location = 0) uniform mat4 projection;
layout (location = 1) uniform mat4 modelview;
layout (location = 2) uniform float posX;
layout (location = 3) uniform float posY;
layout (location = 4) uniform uint posZ;

out vec4 v_color;

void main()
{

    float tmpX = posX;
    float tmpY = posY;
    uint tmpZ = posZ;

    gl_Position = projection * modelview * vec4(in_Vertex.x + tmpX*2, in_Vertex.y + tmpY*2, in_Vertex.z + tmpZ, 1.0) + vec4(in_Color, 0.0);

    v_color = vec4(in_Color,1.0);
}
```

The in_Vertex is working fine but the in_Color seems to have bad values, I send the data as :

```
glUseProgram(m_shaderPerso.getID());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);

        glVertexAttribPointer(5, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);

            glVertexAttribPointer(6, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(m_offsetColor));
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);

                glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ibo);


                    glUniformMatrix4fv(0, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
                    glUniformMatrix4fv(1, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelview));

                    for( auto &x : m_mapPos)
                    {
                        glUniform1f(2, x.second.getX());
                        glUniform1f(3, x.second.getY());
                        glUniform1ui(4, s_map->getHauteur(x.second.getXint(),x.second.getYint()));

                        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_tailleI, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
                    }


                glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

            glDisableVertexAttribArray(6);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(5);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glUseProgram(m_shaderPerso.getID());
```

And I initialize the VBO with :

```
glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo); //Verrouillage VBO

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (tailleV * sizeof(float)) + (m_tailleI*3 * sizeof(float)), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Allocation memoire

    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, tailleV * sizeof(float), m_vertices); //Transfert données vertices

    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tailleV * sizeof(float), m_tailleI*3 * sizeof(float), m_color); //Transfert données couleurs

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


glGenBuffers(1, &m_ibo); //Generation IBO (indices)

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ibo); //Verrouillage IBO

    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_tailleI * sizeof(GLubyte), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Allocation memoire

    glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, m_tailleI * sizeof(GLubyte), m_indices); //Transfert données

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

I really don't know where my mistake is, so I gave you all the code that could be usefull. I do know that the arrays m_vertices, m_color and m_indices are correctly initialized, and the vertices are correctly display, so the VBO for the vertices and the indices are good in the VRAM. I probably done a mistake when I sended the data but I can't find it for 2 days, and I think that a new look could help me.

Thanks for reading and probably helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides what @HolyBlackCat said, you are mixing [interleaved mode with batch mode](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices). When your are filling your buffer, you are using batch mode:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo); //Verrouillage VBO
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (tailleV * sizeof(float)) + (m_tailleI*3 * sizeof(float)), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Allocation memoire
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, tailleV * sizeof(float), m_vertices); //Transfert données vertices
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tailleV * sizeof(float), m_tailleI*3 * sizeof(float), m_color); //Transfert données couleurs
```

First you fill with vertices points, and, at the end of the buffer, with color attributes.

But when you are using the buffer, you are using it in interleaved mode*:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(5, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glVertexAttribPointer(6, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(m_offsetColor));
```

Choose one and stick with it.

*in `glVertexAttribPointer` function, `stride` can have an incorrect value.

Probably, you can solve your problem by changing:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(6, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(m_offsetColor))
```

to:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(6, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), BUFFER_OFFSET(tailleV * sizeof(float)))
```